# Laravel get records resides in month and year

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am using `Laravel 5.2`.

I have a database table `schedules` as:

```
id    name     start_date    end_date
1     AAAAA    2016-01-01    2016-12-31
2     BBBBB    2016-02-01    2016-03-31
3     CCCCC    2016-04-01    2016-06-12
4     DDDDD    2016-04-18    2016-07-15
5     EEEEE    2016-03-15    2016-04-14
6     FFFFF    2016-05-01    2016-08-26
```

Now, I want to fetch the records of schedules that are `resides in current month` i.e. `April-2016`. The result should be

```
id    name     start_date    end_date
1     AAAAA    2016-01-01    2016-12-31
3     CCCCC    2016-04-01    2016-06-12
4     DDDDD    2016-04-18    2016-07-15
5     EEEEE    2016-03-15    2016-04-14
```

I tried using,

```
Schedule::whereDate('start_date', '<=', '2016-04-01')
->whereDate('end_date', '>=', '2016-04-30')
->get();
```

But it excludes records with `id` `1` and `4`.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: why don't you try like this, if we store timestamp in start_date and end_date, and use between query.

Comment: It exclude 1 and 4? Not 4 and 5?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code pass your criterias. Try it.

```
DB::select(DB::raw("SELECT * FROM schedules WHERE start_date <= '2016-04-30' AND end_date >= '2016-04-01'"))
```

Or with Eloquent:

```
Schedule::where('start_date','<=', '2016-04-30')->where('end_date','>=', '2016-04-01')->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

Check for both inclusive & overlapping date ranges:

```
Schedule::where(function($q) use($start_date,$end_date) {
    //Inclusive Date Range
    return $q->orWhere(function($q) use($start_date,$end_date) {
        return $q->where('start_date','>=',$start_date)
            ->where('end_date','<=',$end_date);
    })
    //Overlapping Date Range
    ->orWhere(function($q) use($start_date,$end_date) {
        return $q->where('start_date','<=',$start_date)
            ->where('end_date','>=',$end_date);
    });
})
->get();
```